# How can Python solve inequalities from a String?

Tags: python, string, sympy, inequality

I use the sympy's `solveset` to solve inequalities in Python.
For example, if I want to solve `(10000 / x) - 1 < 0`, I can do this:

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
print(sympy.solveset((10000 / x) - 1 < 0, x, sympy.S.Reals))
```

What can I do to ask Python to solve a inequality, except that it is enclosed in quotes? For instance, `"x**2 > 4, x"`. I tried to search it up, however, all I have found where how to solve "hard-coded" inequalities.

Comment: does this help? https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html

Comment: Thank you @warped ! I would take a look at that. Please put that in the answer box and I will mark it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string. Scipy has a parsing module that should do the trick:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html

Comment: Thank you @warped for helping me! If you want to see what I made with sympy, click https://replit.com/@EmmaGao8/Equation-Solver-II#main.py

My major project: https://replit.com/@EmmaGao8/LennyBot#main.py